# How to store a file from SFTP in Laravel 5.5. Using Flysystem Lib

Tags: php, sftp, laravel-5.5

I am using Flysystem to get files from a SFTP server, getting files and download works fine, **I want to store it in my storage folder.** my code is below:

```
    $adapter = new SftpAdapter([
        'host' => 'demo.wftpserver.com:2222',
        'username' => 'demo-user',
        'password' => 'demo-user',
    ]);

    $filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);

    $abc = Storage::disk('sftp')->get('upload/fo.png', $filesystem);

        //$filesystem->copy('upload/fo.png', 'storage/');

    if ($abc) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
```

Thats the code so far just to get the file, i would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this, Thanks.

Comment: i don't use laravel, so humor me what is `$abc` the contents of the file?  if yes, just do `file_put_contents` or the "laravel" equivalent.

Comment: yeah, the variable abc gets the contents of the file fetched from sftp.
Let me try that. thanks